# Permission denied trying `docker-compose build` in virtualbox shared folder

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-compose, virtualbox, shared-directory

I get `.IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './docker-compose.yml'` when trying to run `docker-compose build` inside shared folder from virtualbox. Even if I try it with `sudo`.

My host machine runs windows 10 and guest OS is ubuntu 18.04.2.

The directory is mounted from virtualbox GUI as permanent, auto-mounted shared folder.

To access this folder I added my user to `vboxsf` group.

`sudo chown -R user /mount/projects` has no effect.

**UPDATE**

Using just a `Dockerfile` with hello-world and commands `docker build --tag=sometag .` and `docker run sometag` works perfectly.

Here is content of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile is the same with hello-world.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by reinstalling docker with:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker.sh
sudo apt install docker-compose
```

And adding my user to gruop `docker`.

Comment: I've installed docker with this script:  
`sudo snap install docker  
sudo groupadd docker  
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER  
sudo chown root:$USER /var/run/docker.sock`  
  
And got the `ERROR: .IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './docker-compose.yml'`  
after running `sudo docker-compose up`  
  
Found your last line tip and it worked:  
`sudo apt install docker-compose`  
  
thanks